# A relation between the eigenvectors of the original matrix and the submatrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

So, in case of Hermitian matrix we know by the interlacing theorem that the eigenvalues of a principal submatrix have an interlacing structure. I am wondering if there is a similar result when observing the eigenvectors. Can we relate the eigenvectors of the original matrix to the eigenvectors of the submatrix?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I don't even understand how the question makes sense. The eigenvectors of the original matrix live in $\Bbb C^n$; those of a submatrix live in a tilted $k$-dimensional subspace.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just thinking if we delete from the original matrix a column and row we can relate somehow the entries of the eigenvectors of the original matrix to the eigenvectors of the submatrix...

Comment: I think trying $2\times 2$ matrices will soon convince you this doesn't go very far.

Comment: @Waikiki It's not exactly what you're looking for but there is an interesting relationship between the [eigenvalues of a submatrix](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/08/13/eigenvectors-from-eigenvalues/) and the eigenvectors/eigenvalues of the original matrix